# Is this method of data binding in Android suitable for production use? Does it contain hidden problems?

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding, kotlin, rx-java2

I'm working on an Android app and I want to implement the MVVM pattern, which is pretty much the standard pushed by Google, however, I'd like to avoid using Android Data Bindings library if possible, since I hate autogenerated XML magic.

I've tried to implement something essentially akin to databinding in RxJava (Kotlin) using Jake Wharton's data binding library, plus some helpful extension methods.

My question is, is this the right way to go about things? Is this good enough to use in production? Are there potential problems I'm not seeing with this approach that will pop up later?

---

Essentially, I've implemented it like this:

I have a `MvvmFragment` (there is a similar class for activities) which takes care of setting up and managing the lifecycle of a `CompositeDisposable` object.

Then, in my `ViewModel` (part of the android Arch ViewModel package) I have all of the fields that will be bound to declared like this:

```
var displayName = BindableVar("")
var email = BindableVar("")
var signInProvider = BindableVar<AuthProvider>(defaultValue = AuthProvider.PASSWORD)
```

(Side note - Since Rx doesn't allow null values, I'm not sure how to handle the case of defaults for objects where the concept of a default doesn't really make sense, such as the `AuthProvider` above)

The `BindableVar` class is implemented like this:

```
class BindableVar<T>(defaultValue: T) {

    var value: T = defaultValue
        set(value) {
            field = value
            observable.onNext(value)
        }

    var observable = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(value)!!

}
```

Using Jake Wharton's RxBindings library, I have created some helpful extension methods on top of that, such as:

```
fun Disposable.addTo(compositeDisposable: CompositeDisposable): Disposable {
    compositeDisposable.add(this)
    return this
}

fun TextView.bindTextTo(string: BindableVar<String>): Disposable {
    return string.observable.subscribe(this.text())
}

fun View.bindVisibilityTo(visibility: Int) {
    // ... not shown
}

fun ImageView.bindImageUriTo(
        src: BindableVar<Uri>, @DrawableRes placeholder: Int? = null
): Disposable {
    return if (placeholder == null) {
        src.observable.subscribe {
            GlideApp.with(context).load(it).into(this)
        }
    } else {
        src.observable.subscribe {
            GlideApp.with(context).load(it).placeholder(placeholder).into(this)
        }
    }
}
```

Using these extension methods, I then obtain the `ViewModel` instance on Fragment initialization, and call a method `initBindings()`, which looks something like this:

```
item_display_name_value.bindTextTo(viewModel.displayName).addTo(bindings)
item_email_address_value.bindTextTo(viewModel.email).addTo(bindings)
item_profile_picture_view.bindImageUrlTo(viewModel.avatarUrl).addTo(bindings)
```

I want to avoid getting a week into fleshing out this architecture and then suddenly realizing there is some critical problem that can't be solved easily, or some other hidden gotcha. Should I just go with XML based data binding? I've heard a lot of complaints about the difficulty of unit-testing it, and the difficulty of reusing code with it.

Comment: Just my two cents. Databinding is pretty simple to use. You have observables and you simply set the activity or fragment variable in onCreate and use it's observable children throughout your xml. It handles the ugly blackbox code. Looks like you have to do the bloat of wiring up your own bindings, and maintain your code way of doing things while the rest of the Android community goes towards the Android standards. I wouldn't recommend building your own way of doing what is already widely accepted, you'll end up regretting it later, but that's just my opinion.